# Convert a column in Dataset which have key value pairs into different rows

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I have data in a dataframe , which was obtained from azure eventhub.
Then I convert this data to json object and stored the required data into a dataset as shown below.

Code for obtaining data from eventhub and store it into a dataframe.

```scala
val connectionString = ConnectionStringBuilder(<ENDPOINT URL>)
    .setEventHubName(<EVENTHUB NAME>).build

val currTime = Instant.now
val ehConf = EventHubsConf(connectionString)
    .setConsumerGroup("<CONSUMER GRP>")
    .setStartingPosition(EventPosition
             .fromEnqueuedTime(currTime.minus(Duration.ofMinutes(30))))
    .setEndingPosition(EventPosition.fromEnqueuedTime(currTime))

val reader =  spark.read.format("eventhubs").options(ehConf.toMap).load()

var SIGNALS =  reader
    .select(get_json_object(($"body").cast("string"),"$.NUM").alias("NUM"),
            get_json_object(($"body").cast("string"),"$.SIG1").alias("SIG1"),
            get_json_object(($"body").cast("string"),"$.SIG2").alias("SIG2"),
            get_json_object(($"body").cast("string"),"$.SIG3").alias("SIG3"),
            get_json_object(($"body").cast("string"),"$.SIG4").alias("SIG4")
     )

val SIGNALSFiltered = SIGNALS.filter(col("SIG1").isNotNull &&
    col("SIG2").isNotNull && col("SIG3").isNotNull && col("SIG4").isNotNull)
```

The data obtained at **SIGNALSFiltered** is shown below.

```
+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|              NUM|                SIG1|                SIG2|                SIG3|                SIG4|
+-----------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|XXXXX01|[{"TIME":15695605310...|[{"TIME":15695605310...|[{"TIME":15695605310...|[{"TIME":15695605310...|
|XXXXX02|[{"TIME":15695604780...|[{"TIME":15695604780...|[{"TIME":15695604780...|[{"TIME":15695604780...|
|XXXXX03|[{"TIME":15695605310...|[{"TIME":15695605310...|[{"TIME":15695605310...|[{"TIME":15695605310...|
|XXXXX04|[{"TIME":15695605310...|[{"TIME":15695605310...|[{"TIME":15695605310...|[{"TIME":15695605310...|
|XXXXX05|[{"TIME":15695605310...|[{"TIME":15695605310...|[{"TIME":15695605310...|[{"TIME":15695605310...|
|XXXXX06|[{"TIME":15695605340...|[{"TIME":15695605340...|[{"TIME":15695605340...|[{"TIME":15695605340...|
|XXXXX07|[{"TIME":15695605310...|[{"TIME":15695605310...|[{"TIME":15695605310...|[{"TIME":15695605310...|
|XXXXX08|[{"TIME":15695605310...|[{"TIME":15695605310...|[{"TIME":15695605310...|[{"TIME":15695605310...|
```

If we check entire data for a single row it will be as below.

```
|XXXXX01|[{"TIME":1569560531000,"VALUE":3.7825},{"TIME":1569560475000,"VALUE":3.7812},{"TIME":1569560483000,"VALUE":1.7812},{"TIME":1569560491000,"VALUE":7.7875}]|
    [{"TIME":1569560537000,"VALUE":3.7825},{"TIME":1569560481000,"VALUE":9.7825},{"TIME":1569560489000,"VALUE":5.7825},{"TIME":1569560497000,"VALUE":34.7825}]|
    [{"TIME":1569560505000,"VALUE":34.7825},{"TIME":1569560513000,"VALUE":9.7825},{"TIME":1569560521000,"VALUE":34.7825},{"TIME":1569560527000,"VALUE":4.7825}]|
    [{"TIME":1569560535000,"VALUE":7.7825},{"TIME":1569560479000,"VALUE":35.7825},{"TIME":1569560487000,"VALUE":3.7825}]
```

I want to convert each time-value pair in each signals column into a new row.

Is there Any way to convert the base dataset as below?. Each elements in a column should be converted to a new row.

```
+-----------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|    NUM|    SIG1 TIME| SIG1 VALUE|    SIG2 TIME|   SIG2 VALUE|    SIG3 TIME|   SIG3 VALUE|    SIG4 TIME|  SIG4 VALUE |
+-----------------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------------+-----------------------------+
|XXXXX01|1569560531000|     3.7825|1569560531000|       4.7825|1569560531000|       8.7825|1569560531000|       2.7825|
|XXXXX01|1569560531000|     1.7825|1569560531000|       1.7825|        null |       null  |1569560531000|       2.7825|
|XXXXX01|1569560531000|     3.7825|1569560531000|       4.7825|1569560531000|       8.7825|1569560531000|       7.7825|
|XXXXX02|1569560531000|     7.7825|1569560531000|       4.7825|1569560531000|       8.7825|1569560531000|       2.7825|
|XXXXX02|null         |     null  |1569560531000|       5.7825|1569560531000|       7.7825|1569560531000|       5.7825|
|XXXXX02|1569560531000|     3.7825|1569560531000|       4.7825|1569560531000|       8.7825|1569560531000|       2.7825|
|XXXXX02|1569560531000|     5.7825|1569560531000|       7.7825|1569560531000|       9.7825|1569560531000|       2.7825|
```

Any leads or help is appreciated! Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using the `explode` function. It will generate new row for each element in your array and then you can access the fields `time` and `value` using the dot syntax (accessing fields of a struct). Here is a simple example for the first column:

```
data
.withColumn("sig1_obj", explode($"SIG1"))
.withColumn("sig1_time", $"sig1_obj.time")
.withColumn("sig1_value", $"sig1_obj.value")
.show()

+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+----------+
|                SIG1|            sig1_obj|    sig1_time|sig1_value|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+----------+
|[[1569560531000, ...|[1569560531000, 3...|1569560531000|    3.7825|
|[[1569560531000, ...|[1569560475000, 3...|1569560475000|    3.7812|
|[[1569560531000, ...|[1569560483000, 1...|1569560483000|    1.7812|
|[[1569560531000, ...|[1569560491000, 7...|1569560491000|    7.7875|
+--------------------+--------------------+-------------+----------+
```

Similarly you can handle also the other columns.

Also notice that using this technique it is going to multiply the data, for the second column, you will get `n*m` rows, where `n` is number of elements in sig1 array and `m` is number of elements in sig2 array and so on. If you do not want that, you can explode each column in a separate dataframe and than full-outer join these dataframes on some fields (perhaps row_number the rows for each `NUM` and join on the the `NUM` col and row_number)

Edit:

Since you are having StringType in your sig columns, you can first convert this String field to Array of Structs using `from_json` function. In your example it can be done as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructField, StructType, ArrayType, StringType}

val schema = ArrayType(StructType(Seq(StructField("TIME", StringType), StructField("VALUE", StringType))))

df.withColumn("sig1_arr", from_json($"SIG1", schema))
```

Comment: Yes I tried explode function also but it was failing due to type mismatch for Signals. Signals are not in type of Array or Map.

```scala> SIGNALSFiltered.printSchema root |-- NUM: string (nullable = true) |-- SIG1: string (nullable = true) |-- SIG2: string (nullable = true) |-- SIG3: string (nullable = true) |-- SIG4: string (nullable = true)```@David Vrba

Comment: @Antony Ok, but if the string is in a form of array of structs it can be converted using from_json function with provided schema. See the updated answer

Comment: Since the column which i have to convert is type of String as I commented above, this solution is not working. Have to convert the Signal column from type String to Struct/Array before applying this solution. @David Vrba

Comment: @Antony Sorry, the specified schema was wrong, i edited the answer and changed the schema. It is working for me now.

Comment: @Antony It is important to use a correct schema otherwise the result will be null values as you got.

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> SIGNALSFiltered.show(false)
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|NUM    |SIG1                                                                                                          |SIG2                                                                                                            |SIG3                                                                                                             |SIG4                                                                                 |
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|XXXXX01|[{"TIME":11,"VALUE":3.7825},{"TIME":12,"VALUE":3.7812},{"TIME":13,"VALUE":3.7812},{"TIME":14,"VALUE":34.7875}]|[{"TIME":21,"VALUE":3.7825},{"TIME":22,"VALUE":34.7825},{"TIME":23,"VALUE":34.7825},{"TIME":24,"VALUE":34.7825}]|[{"TIME":31,"VALUE":34.7825},{"TIME":32,"VALUE":34.7825},{"TIME":33,"VALUE":34.7825},{"TIME":34,"VALUE":34.7825}]|[{"TIME":41,"VALUE":34.7825},{"TIME":42,"VALUE":34.7825},{"TIME":43,"VALUE":34.7825}]|
+-------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+


scala>  import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
scala>  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.arrays_zip
scala>  import scala.util.parsing.json._

scala>    def flatTime:UserDefinedFunction = udf((json:String) => {
     |    val pars = JSON.parseFull(json)
     |    var outputList = new ListBuffer[String]()
     |    pars.foreach{ x => 
     |    val y = x.asInstanceOf[List[Any]]
     |    y.foreach{ zz =>
     |    val z =  zz.asInstanceOf[Map[String,Double]]
     |     val tempStr = """[{"TIME" : """ + z("TIME").toString + """ ,"VALUE": """ +  z("VALUE").toString + """}]"""
     |     outputList += tempStr
     |   }
     |   }
     |   outputList.toList
     |   })

scala> SIGNALSFiltered.withColumn("var", explode(arrays_zip(flatTime(col("SIG1")),flatTime(col("SIG2")),flatTime(col("SIG3")),flatTime(col("SIG4"))))).select(col("NUM"), col("var.0").alias("SIG1"),col("var.1").alias("SIG2"),col("var.2").alias("SIG3"),col("var.3").alias("SIG4")).show(false)
+-------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|NUM    |SIG1                               |SIG2                               |SIG3                               |SIG4                               |
+-------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
|XXXXX01|[{"TIME" : 11.0 ,"VALUE": 3.7825}] |[{"TIME" : 21.0 ,"VALUE": 3.7825}] |[{"TIME" : 31.0 ,"VALUE": 34.7825}]|[{"TIME" : 41.0 ,"VALUE": 34.7825}]|
|XXXXX01|[{"TIME" : 12.0 ,"VALUE": 3.7812}] |[{"TIME" : 22.0 ,"VALUE": 34.7825}]|[{"TIME" : 32.0 ,"VALUE": 34.7825}]|[{"TIME" : 42.0 ,"VALUE": 34.7825}]|
|XXXXX01|[{"TIME" : 13.0 ,"VALUE": 3.7812}] |[{"TIME" : 23.0 ,"VALUE": 34.7825}]|[{"TIME" : 33.0 ,"VALUE": 34.7825}]|[{"TIME" : 43.0 ,"VALUE": 34.7825}]|
|XXXXX01|[{"TIME" : 14.0 ,"VALUE": 34.7875}]|[{"TIME" : 24.0 ,"VALUE": 34.7825}]|[{"TIME" : 34.0 ,"VALUE": 34.7825}]|null                               |
+-------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+-----------------------------------+
```